# In Puppet using Hiera, where do I put the files I want to have installed on nodes?

Tags: puppet, hiera

I know puppet modules always have a files directory and I know where it's supposed to be and I have used the **source =>** syntax effectively from my own, handwritten modules but now I need to learn how to deploy files using Hiera.

I'm starting with the saz-sudo module and I've read the docs but I can't see anything about where to put the sudoers file; the one I want to distribute. 
I'm not sure whether I need to set up a site-wide files dir in /etc/puppetlabs/puppet and then make subdirs in there for every module or what. And does Hiera know to look in /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/files/sudo if I say, **source => "puppet:///files/etc/sudoers"** ? Do I need to add a pathname in /etc/hiera.yaml? Add a line **- files** ?

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 1):

My cursory view of the puppet module, given their example of using hiera:

```
sudo::configs:
'web':
    'source'    : 'puppet:///files/etc/sudoers.d/web'
'admins':
    'content'   : "%admins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL"
    'priority'  : 10
'joe':
    'priority'  : 60
    'source'    : 'puppet:///files/etc/sudoers.d/users/joe'
```

Suggest it assumes you have a "files" puppet module.  So under you puppet modules section:

```
mkdir -p files/files/etc/sudoers.d/
```

Drop your files in there.

Explanation:

The url 'puppet:///files/etc/sudoers.d/users/joe' is broken down thus:

```
puppet: protocol
///:  Three slashes indicate the source of the file is in a module.
files: name of the module
etc/sudoers.d/users/joe:  full path to the file within the module's "files" directory.
```

Comment: I think I was temporarily insane regarding that file url.  It's not a module it's looking for.  Module paths are 'puppet:///modules/mod_name/etc'.
The one in question is assuming you have a "file" share setup on your puppet master.  See http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/file_serving.html for details on how to set that up.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

The idea of a module (Hiera backed or not) is to lift the need to manage the whole sudoers file from you. Instead, you can manage each single entry in the sudoers file.

I recommend reviewing the [documentation](https://github.com/saz/puppet-sudo#adding-sudoers-configuration) carefully. You should definitely **not** have a `file { "/etc/sudoers": }` resource in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Hiera doesn't have to do anything with Files.

Hiera is like a Variables Database, and servers you based on the hierarchy you have.

the files inside puppet, are usually accessed in methods like **source =>** but also these files are using some basic structure.

In most cases when you call an ***file*** or ***template***.

A template can serve your needs to automatically build an sudoers based on that.
There are also modules that supports modifying sudoers too.

It is up to you what to do.

In this case, saz stores the location of the file in hiera, but the real location can be a file inside your puppet (like a module file or something similar).

Which is completely unrelated.
Read about [puppet file server](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/file_serving.html)

If you have questions, just ask.

V